# How do I select an element that has a certain class?

Tags: html, css, syntax, css-selectors

My understanding is that using `element.class` should allow for a specific element assigned to a class to receive different "styling" than the rest of the class. This is not a question about whether this should be used or not, but rather I'm trying to understand how this selector is intended to work. From looking at a ton of examples on the internet, I believe the syntax is correct and do not understand why this is not working.

Here is an example:

CSS:

```
h2 {
    color: red;
}

.myClass {
    color: green;
}

h2.myClass {
    color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>This header should be RED to match the h2 element selector</h2>
<div class="myClass">
    <h1>This header should be GREEN to match the class selector</h1>
    <h2>This header should be BLUE to match the element.class selector</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be worth updating the question title to reflect that you are actually asking how element.class selectors work, not why they don't work the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 122):

It should be this way:

`h2.myClass` looks for h2 with class `myClass`. But you actually want to apply style for h2 inside `.myClass` so you can use descendant selector `.myClass h2`.

```
h2 {
    color: red;
}

.myClass {
    color: green;
}

.myClass h2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sEQcn/)

This [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) will give you some basic idea about the selectors and have a look at [descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

Comment: To be clear I am trying to under stand how the element.class selector works. I am specifically trying to use the element.class syntax to override the color of the element (h2 that's in myClass) to blue as opposed to the class color of green. I'd like to know how to target a specific element under a class.

Comment: @Carolyn if you want that then you need use myClass on h2. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/wDmwE/. Reason is css rule on h2 will override class .myClass on the container.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, your answer did help. I guess my problem was with specificity (I'm just learning about that). Thanks again!. Much appreciated.

Comment: Finally. I was looking for this solution for a long time. I knew about elementWithAClass.Class { }, but not about .Class elementInsideThisClass { }. Thank you. I owe you a beer :D

Answer (score 69):

`h2.myClass` refers to all `h2` with `class="myClass"`.

`.myClass h2` refers to all `h2` that are children of (i.e. nested in) elements with `class="myClass"`.

If you want the `h2` in your HTML to appear blue, change the CSS to the following:

```
.myClass h2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

If you want to be able to reference that `h2` by a class rather than its tag, you should leave the CSS as it is and give the `h2` a class in the HTML:

```
<h2 class="myClass">This header should be BLUE to match the element.class selector</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm actually trying to understand how to use the element.class selector. I want all the h2 elements under "myClass"

Comment: @Carolyn, does my updated answer help?  If not, then I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I'm still trying to wrap my head around specificity.

Comment: @Carolyn is there something in particular you're having trouble with?

Comment: ASGM - I was having trouble understanding how the element.class selector works. Since I posted I've learned a bit more (along with the information provided on this site), so I was not using them correctly. Thanks,

Comment: Should be top answer.

Answer (score 15):

The element.class selector is for styling situations such as this:

```
<span class="large"> </span>
<p class="large"> </p>

.large {
    font-size:150%; font-weight:bold;
}

p.large {
    color:blue;
}
```

Both your span and p will be assigned the font-size and font-weight from .large, but the color blue will only be assigned to p.

As others have pointed out, what you're working with is descendant selectors.

Comment: Thank you. Very much. Everyone has been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`h2.myClass` is only valid for `h2` elements which got the class `myClass` directly assigned.

Your want to note it like this:

```
.myClass h2
```

Which selects all children of `myClass` which have the tagname `h2`

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `:first-child` selector allows you to target an element that is the first child element within its parent.

```css
element:first-child { style_properties }
table:first-child { style_properties }
```